# Create and add listview to layout at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have design like this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next" />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- the two columns part -->

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.80"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.80" 
        android:id="@+id/submenue"
        >

         <!-- this will be the menue list -->
         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/MyHiddenListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" 
            >



            </ListView>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/contents"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First Name" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.20" 
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="second Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I added the following code to the next button such that it display and fill the list

```
this.next = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
        this.next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String[] MainMenue =  new String[] { "aaaa", "bbb", "ccc"};

                menueview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyHiddenListView);
                menueview.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
                menueview.setAdapter(new submenueadapter(getApplicationContext(), MainMenue));

            }
        });
```

and the adaptor class is

package com.appnetics;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class submenueadapter   extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;


    public submenueadapter(Context context,String[] objects)
    {


        super(context, R.layout.main, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contents);

        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values[position];

        System.out.println(s);


        return rowView;
    }
}
```

the problem is that the list be populated with the array plus the other controls in the page (the 2 buttons )

the layout before clicking next
[image]
the layout after clicking 
[image]
any idea to fix that please

Best regards 
Best regards

Comment: You should use addchild for the layout

Comment: any example, or more explanation please I tried for textview code like that addview to layout and it worked, but  Idon't know how to do the same with listview ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are including everything in one **main.xml** layout.

And due to this problem, you are getting back/next button for every listitem (Actually whole layout is being repeating as Listitem).

**Soluition:**

Instead, Try to define separate layout for the ListItem and inflate that layout inside the getView() method. so there must be 2 XML layouts file, one is having main design with ListView only, and another one with only views that you want for every list item.

for example, (1) main.xml (2) row_item.xml

Now, you just need to make correction in code of inflating layout:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);  // row_item.xml is inflated here
```

Answer (score 2):

ViewGroup class do offers various methods to add view anywhere and using LayoutParams classes you can pass the various parent container class specific attributes to applied over the child view to be added in the container.

That you can google and is easily doable.

I can also think of putting a ListView in the XML with the Visibility GONE.

And on specific action trigger make it visible. That will prevent me doing various programing stuff required to add view at a perticular position. 
And i also don't feel any harm of this approach.

e.g

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/MyHiddenListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
</Linearlayout>
```

In the .java file

```
btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyHiddenListView);

btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      myListView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
      myListView.setAdaptor(new MyListViewAdaptor());
   }
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: shall I put textview in the list to fill it using the adaptor

Comment: how to fill it dynamically, the adaptor as I know need textview to fill according to   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 
  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
  TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
  textView.setText(values[position]);